# How to maintain the integrity of the data from the columns in the tables in the database

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, mariadb

I want to keep the character `/r/n` for "history" data and I don't want to omit the "/r/n" when displayed in the HTML.

```
public function get3Tbl($id_siswa)
{
    return DB::table('tbl_siswa')
        ->join('tbl_mapel', 'tbl_siswa.id_mapel', '=', 'tbl_mapel.id_mapel')
        ->join('tbl_guru', 'tbl_siswa.id_guru', '=', 'tbl_guru.id_guru')
        ->join('tbl_wiki', 'tbl_siswa.id_wiki', '=', 'tbl_wiki.id_wiki')
        ->addSelect('nis')
        ->addSelect('nama_siswa')
        ->addSelect('tbl_mapel.mapel')
        ->addSelect('tbl_guru.nama_guru')
        ->addSelect('foto_siswa')
        ->addSelect('tbl_wiki.adaptasi')
        ->addSelect('tbl_wiki.total_eps')
        ->addSelect('tbl_wiki.thn_produksi')
        ->addSelect('tbl_wiki.history')
        ->addSelect('tbl_wiki.description_char')
        ->where('tbl_wiki.id_siswa', $id_siswa)
        ->first();
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: then on your blade use `{!! $data !!}` instead of `{{ $data }}`

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: how did you try to display on html?

Comment: I googled and found the method in the Laracast community. and the discussion mentions the "nl2br()" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for not printing you can use {!! $value !!} , it just print what ever is in the $value